# iOS-Autolayout design: Increase button height as device height changes

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, swift3

In my application I have added a `UIButton` with following `constraints`:

```
Leading space = 10
Trailing space = 10
Height = 50
Bottom space =10
```

By this I got a `button` placed at a bottom of device. It works good on single device(iPhone 4), but as device height increases button height remains same(iPhone 6).

I want to change button height also with `Autolayout`.

I tried some example which suggest to add `multiplier` value but no luck.

I am using Xcode-8 with Swift3

Please suggest me.

Comment: adding multiplier helps your question

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to handle this issue
First:-
Create 1,Give Fixed Height Constraint to button 
       2.Create @IBOutlet of Height Constraint
        like this way

```
 @IBOutlet weak var btnHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

   3. Set Constraint constant as per your requirement
```

like this way.

```
btnHeightConstraint.constant = 50 //your button height 50
btnHeightConstraint.constant = 60 //your button height 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Set all the constarints which is needed and set 'Equal Height' constraint with your 'superview' and set the multiplier value i.e if your view size is same as iphone 5 then set multiplier value as 'yourHeight:568', you will get required output.